# Как получить конкретное значение из бд sql в python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord, discord.py

У меня есть код написанный на discord.py и sqlite3:

```
for players in cursor.execute("""SELECT player1 FROM lobby WHERE id = ?""", [0]):
    if players[0] == None:
        cursor.execute("""UPDATE lobby SET player1 = ? WHERE id = ?""", (ctx.author.id, 0))
        sqlite_connection.commit()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"[1/10] {ctx.author.mention} присоединился к очереди"
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    print(players[0])
```

переменная p1 выдает: ('None',), а мне надо получить просто None без лишних символов как я могу это сделать?

Comment: попробуйте p1 = cursor.fetchone()[0]

Comment: ошибка вообще какая-то

Comment: @portside, наверное, у вас той записи не было и `fetchone` вернул `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вытаскивать значения из базы данных можно с помощью `for`, `in`:

```
for test in cursor.execute("""SELECT player1 FROM lobby WHERE id = ?""", [0]):
```

Мы назвали переменную `test`. Теперь **`player1`** можно использовать как **`test[0]`**. Например:

```
if test[0] == None: #Вместо None лучше использовать значение по умолчанию в Вашей таблице..
```

Последующие значения, например `SELECT player1, player2, player3 FROM` мы получаем как `test[0]`, `test[1]`, `test[2]` и т.д.

Полный код:

```
for test in cursor.execute("""SELECT player1 FROM lobby WHERE id = ?""", [0]):
    if test[0] == None:
        ....
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142548/discussion-on-answer-by-q-r-t-s-------sql--pyt); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.